# My discord bot command returns same response 3 times

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a discord bot and when I type `ping!` in the channel, the bot replies with `pong!` three times:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("Ready");

});

client.login("NzcyNzI0MDYzMTc3MTQ2MzY4.X5-1XQ.2xXEMz_ZNAYuHK9GbokDixIOCsY");

client.on("message", message =>{
    if(message.content === "!ping") {
        message.channel.send("Pong!");
    }else if(message.content === "Hi!") {
        message.channel.send("Hello");
    }
    
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably shouldnt post your discord bot token out. 

This question have been asked a lot of times, most common reason being you running the the bot multiple times in other instances (in other Commend Line/Terminal). Close other instances probably solve this issues.

Comment: @Bulaxy I will change the token thats not an issue. I remember using  node .\index.js quite a few times is this problem? what do you mean by closing other instances? Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: If you run `node .\index.js` a few times in without closing/stopping them, then that's probably the problem. If it response 3 times, it probably means you are running 3 of them. close other instances just means stop/close the other places where you running `node .\index.js` until you only have 1 left